# Databinding custom objects and populating controls with unique values etc

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a custom object that gets values form a table in a db.  Lets call it - **Product** table.
My code populates a `List<Product>` and binds to several comboboxes using `myCombobox.DisplayMember = "Country"` in order to display the correct values.

Here's the sample code (nothing out of the ordinary, OnFormLoad()).

```
DatabaseTools dbTools = new DatabaseTools();
List<Product> productList = dbTools.GetProducts();

cboCountry.BeginUpdate();
cboCountry.DataSource = productList ;
cboCountry.DisplayMember = "Country";
cboCountry.EndUpdate();
```

Simple enough.  However some of the values returned from the database are either missing, duplicated or need string formatting before they get displayed in the control.  Is there a way to do this.  Otherwise the data in my comboboxes looks awful:

[image]

Comment: De-duping this is a pain, because I doubt they are "true" duplicates - they probably have different ids, right? also, automated case correction is a pain, because normal rules don't apply to place names - although you might get away with it for countries. IMO the *real* fix here is to fix the data at source.

Comment: Well, yes I agree Marc, the data is not the best, but hey it's what I got lumped with gggrrrrrr! Deduping is probably the priority - I can get the database to the work, using DISTINCT, but that ends up being 5 separate select queries, not great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent duplicated product use a EqualityComparer :

```
 public class ProductCountryEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
    {

        #region IEqualityComparer<Product> Members

        public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
        {
            return x != null && y != null && x.Country  == y.Country;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Then :

```
//That will make products distincts according to there Country
productList = productList.Distinct(new ProductCountryEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

To format country :

```
productList = productList.Distinct(new ProductCountryEqualityComparer())
              .Select(f => new Product() 
              {
               Country = string.Format(f.Country,"SomeFormat") 
              }).ToList();
```

To Order :

```
productList = productList.Distinct(new ProductCountryEqualityComparer())
              .Select(f => new Product() 
              {
               Country = string.Format(f.Country,"SomeFormat") 
              }).OrderBy(f => f.Country).ToList();
```

**Just use last one :)**

Answer (score 1):

Why not LINQ, saves having to hit the database and as you are not using a unique ID for your country objects, this should work...

```
            List<string> countries = new List<string>() 
            { "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Pakistan", "Norway", "Senegal", "Senegal", "Senegal", };
            // Place into a LINQ query and utilise the distinct keyword
            var unique = (from c in countries
                          select c).Distinct().ToArray();
            // Test output
            Array.ForEach<string>(unique, x => Console.WriteLine(x));
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You can't use distinct(on country) on a <Product> list unless you use a IEqualityComparer or select countries from products then use distinct `products.Select(m => m.Country).Distinct();`